# Receive Adium messages in Applescript

Tags: applescript, adium

I'm trying to write a simple chat bot for Adium, that will post "lol" and "haha" and answer basic questions in annoying group chats that some people keep adding me to.

I've covered the "lol" part with a few simple send and delay commands in a repeat, but I need to do some interaction as well.
Answer "yes" to anything with a question mark for example...

Believe me or not, such a simple bot would pass a Turing Test for those conversations.

Opening the Adium dictionary does not reveal any obvious way of getting messages, nor does the Growl dictionary.

I did found out that I can run a script every time a message is received, Is there a way to get access to the sent message?

[Adium pref http://media.ruk.ca/images/adiumpreferences.png](http://media.ruk.ca/images/adiumpreferences.png)

My code:

```
tell application "Adium"
    activate
    set theChat to the active chat
    send theChat message "Hi"
    delay 5
    send theChat message "How's life?"
    delay 10
    repeat 10 times
        send theChat message "Realy?"
        delay 5
        send theChat message "Lol :P"
        delay 15
        send theChat message "Haha XD"
        delay 15
        send theChat message "Yes1!!1"
        delay 20
        send theChat message "I like it! :D"
        delay 10
    end repeat
    send theChat message "Bye!"
    tell theChat to close
end tell
```

Comment: It's "Turing test", as in Alan Turing.  And I have to wonder how many people would pass the Turing test.  Also, in the last question, do you mean that you want to access the *received* message, or the one *you* just sent?

Comment: I'll change it.

Yes, I want to have access to received messages, so I can write a basic chat bot in Applescript.

Comment: I've been wondering this myself for a couple of years and have never found anything of use. I have a feeling its in the interest of the Adium developers to prevent this exact type of thing from happening—despite the good others could use it for.

Comment: I don't see how sending chat messages is any more dangerous than sending emails with AppleScript.

Comment: @Kyle I don't see why the Adium developers would care. If people want to write a chat bot, they can do it through any of the protocols in pretty much any language they want. Unless you're talking about the possibility for malicious scripts taking over your chat - and even then, doing so discretely would be nearly impossible with applescript.

Comment: @Jamie, you make an excellent point actually. It would be better just to write a bot for the protocol outside of Adium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe to a script using [Pipe Event](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=7852) as well now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on review of the current Adium sourcecode and a search for current and past items in the Adium bug tracker and wiki which contain both "applescript" and "message" as substrings, this does not appear to be possible when using only AppleScript in Adium 1.0 through 1.3.10 (latest at time of writing). It seems to have been possible with plain AppleScript in Adium 0.89.1, but the volunteer developers are not yet convinced that adding this feature back is worth the effort.

To access the message content in AppleScript right now probably requires writing an Adium Xtra to forward the information. Examples of Xtra plugins that access the text of last message include [Challenge/Response](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=6177) or [SpamFilter](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=7683). The sourcecode for SpamFilter is [available](https://bitbucket.org/xnyhps/adium-spamfilter-plugin) on BitBucket, so you could conceivably modify it to send message contents to an AppleScript.

EDIT: Since I posted my response, user 'zostay' has spotted a new Adium Xtra called "[Pipe Event](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=7852)". It allows sending the text of an event to a script in exactly the manner I envisioned when I wrote my second paragraph, so I'm up-voting zostay's answer. [Sourcecode](https://github.com/jcs/adium-pipeevent) is also available.